# Fabric8 exec command in pod: piped commands?

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

I'm trying to execute piped commands on a single call in a pod. I'd like to do something more sophisticated, but first I'd like to be able to simply count lines from a ls output like this:

```
    private ExecWatch execCmd(Pod pod, CompletableFuture<String> data, String... command) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        return this.kubernetesClient.pods().inNamespace(pod.getMetadata().getNamespace())
                .withName(pod.getMetadata().getName()).writingOutput(baos).writingError(baos)
                .usingListener(new SimpleListener(data, baos)).exec(command);
    }
```

And then

```
        CompletableFuture<String> data = new CompletableFuture<>();
        try (ExecWatch execWatch = execCmd(pod, data, "ls", "-lrt", "internal_folder/", "| wc -l"))         {
            result = data.get(executionTimeout.getSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
```

No matter how do I arrange the command: "|", "wc","-l"; or "internal_folder/ | wc -l"; and many others, it always results on: "ls: cannot access '| wc -l': No such file or directory"

How could I do this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to do it in two separate exec calls? Collect output in first exec for `ls` then consume that output in second exec? If not, could you please create an issue on Fabric8 GitHub?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Rohan. Unfortunately I cannot write on the file system. However, my intention is not to be able to get the number of lines, but to join shell commands for more complicated sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing whole command as input to `sh -c`. I tested it with this code on Fabric8 Kubernetes Client v6.9.2 and it seems to work for me:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().build()) {
  PodResource podResource = client.pods()
      .inNamespace("default")
      .withName("exrf9fr");
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
  try (ExecWatch execWatch = podResource.writingOutput(baos).terminateOnError()
      .exec("sh", "-c", "ls -lrt /proc | wc -l")) {

    execWatch.exitCode().join();
  }

  System.out.println("Result : " + baos);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, Rohan! I will test it whenever I get back to work and I´ll share my findings :)

Comment: Hi Rohan. Including "sh" "-c" first did work for me! Thanks. Now if I'd like to filter my results by, for example, size I try "... | awk '{if($5>1000){print$0}}'" and this is not working for me. It says "sh: awk: command not found", however this is working if I perform "kubernetes exec ... | awk '{if($5>1000){print$0}}'" directly in console.

Comment: Could you please share full command with me so that I can try? Which image are you using?

Comment: Thanks, Rohan. What do you mean with "image"? I'm working with v6.9.2 as well. The full command would be: "sh", "-c", "ls -lrt /proc | awk '{if($5>1000){print$0}}'". Thank you again :)